# Beautiful Soup Parsing table within a div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on using bs4 to pull information from listings on ebay to obtain details on products, I'm attempting to produce a result using [this](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/HP-250-G5-15-6-Intel-Celeron-500GB-4GB-USB-3-0-DVD-Bluetooth-Windows-10-Laptop/330618971310?hash=item4cfa6d24ae:g:ZiEAAOSwv-ZaE1-A) listing as an example, the code I'm feeling is most accurate is as below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
attributes = page_soup.findAll("div",{'class':'itemAttr'})
attribute = attributes [0]
row = attribute.tr.contents
```

The idea being, pull the webpage, parse the appropriate div (itemattr), and attempt to pull content from here using the tr/td tags or combination there of. Not included above is my numerous variations of work this, but I can see I hit this roadblock of the parse producing a list (with one item) and navigation through this list is met with road blocks. I did look at directly parsing the table, but unfortunately they haven't given it a class. I'm wondering if there is any ideas on how to pull a table from a div tag, or perhaps create a new subset of html from parse (as opposed to a list?). Or tell me if I've gone insane and should go to bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your current work makes a lot of sense, good job!

To move ahead, we can leverage the structure of the `td` elements on the eBay page, and the fact that they come in two's with a `attrLabels` class on the header to extract the specific data.

This gives you the data in the same order as it appears on the page:

```
tds = attribute.findAll("td")
ordered_data = []
for i in range(0, len(tds), 2):
    if tds[i].get('class') == ['attrLabels']:
        key = tds[i].text.strip().strip(":")
        value = tds[i+1].span.text
        ordered_data.append({ key: value })
```

And this gives you the same thing but in a dict with key-value pairs so that you can easily access each attribute:

```
tds = attribute.findAll("td")
searchable_data = {}
for i in range(0, len(tds), 2):
    if tds[i].get('class') == ['attrLabels']:
        key = tds[i].text.strip().strip(":")
        value = tds[i+1].span.text
        searchable_data[key] = value
```

Comment: You sir are a god among men, this worked perfectly. I'm going to break and re-break this to get the hang of it. Thanks a bunch!